# Extending bibliography limit

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I need to extend the limit for references in BibTeX, it won't let me go over 20 and if I do just comes up with a warning in the Console Output that there are undefined references even though I have both defined and cited them.

Comment: Please post a short example with 20+ references and the error shown in the console.

Comment: Please be sure to indicate which document class and which bibliography style file you're using. I've never before heard of a limit of 20 entries in a BibTeX-generated list of references.

Comment: http://i47.tinypic.com/2envnue.jpg
This is a screenshot, I am using report document class and IEEE referencing style

Comment: I have also posted on LaTeX community, the .log and .blg file has been uploaded on there as well http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=20474

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for posting the links. The .blg file lists two errors that bibtex encountered. (One is a case mis-match in the citation key, the other is about an invalid field -- you can't comment out fields with `%`.) Do things get any better after you've fixed these errors?

Comment: @Mico, it was the invalid fields. After I un-commented them it was fixed. Thanks for the help! Such a simple thing too...

Comment: This should be said for future readers: There IS no (practical) limit to the number of references in your bib database, or in the generated bibliography. The question was based on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by missing field names, as it has been found on [LaTeX-Community.org: Extend Bibliography Database Size](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=20474).

This error in the .blg file pointed to the problem:

```
You're missing a field name---line 12 of file thesis.bib
 :    
 :     %volume   = "",
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

After it was fixed, the problem was gone.